# How to replace NA with missing CSV.read

Tags: csv, julia

I have a problem with replacing the NA, when I read a CSV file via CSV.read(). The dataset contains missing values named NA. If I try it like this:

```
dax = CSV.read("dax.dat"; delim='\t', decimal=',', dateformat="dd.mm.yyyy", null="NA")
```

I get the following error message:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type WeakRefString{UInt8} to an object of type Missings.Missing
```

If I read the file in the following way:

```
dax = CSV.read("dax.dat"; delim='\t', decimal=',', dateformat="dd.mm.yyyy")
```

The columns with NA values are read as strings ... The dataset looks like (a snapshot in the middle):

```
09.11.1995  NA  120.155 7.861   17.616  8.198   12.316
10.11.1995  NA  119.17  7.777   17.51   8.308   12.221
13.11.1995  NA  119.305 7.861   17.51   8.351   12.221
14.11.1995  NA  121.498 7.897   17.582  8.206   12.403
15.11.1995  NA  120.558 7.859   17.395  8.223   12.292
16.11.1995  NA  121.095 8.053   17.558  8.377   12.364
17.11.1995  9,715   121.677 8.091   17.625  8.223   12.395
20.11.1995  9,484   122.707 8.13    17.764  8.181   12.53
21.11.1995  9,446   121.319 8.017   17.616  8.181   12.427
22.11.1995  9,574   120.871 7.963   17.577  8.121   12.372
23.11.1995  9,619   119.663 8.004   17.558  8.13    12.206
```

How could I manage it, that the NA are read as missing?

The complete dataset could be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/drdzstpiyrvw5kc/dax.dat?dl=0

Comment: Can you paste the original CSV of one of the columns having `NA` ?

Comment: your example data reads-in correctly for me. Maybe the file has many rows and you have to set `rows_for_type_detect` to a higher value than 100?

Comment: Yeah, it hast many rows ... Like 11096. The complete dataset could be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/drdzstpiyrvw5kc/dax.dat?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rows_for_type_detect` large enough so that you read something else than `"NA"` in every relevant column:

```
julia> dax = CSV.read("dax.dat"; delim='\t', decimal=',', dateformat="dd.mm.yyyy", null="NA", rows_for_type_detect=11000);

julia> showcols(dax)
11096×31 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Col # │ Name                  │ Eltype                           │ Missing │ Values                    │
├───────┼───────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼───────────────────────────┤
│ 1     │ Date                  │ Date                             │ 0       │ 1973-01-01  …  2015-07-13 │
│ 2     │ ADIDAS                │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 5969    │ missing  …  69.847        │
│ 3     │ ALLIANZ               │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 6.943  …  148.756         │
│ 4     │ BASF                  │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 3.826  …  83.348          │
│ 5     │ BAYER                 │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 5.862  …  135.89          │
│ 6     │ BEIERSDORF            │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 1.672  …  77.625          │
│ 7     │ BMW                   │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 1.644  …  95.14           │
│ 8     │ COMMERZBANK           │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 44.386  …  11.646         │
│ 9     │ CONTINENTAL           │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 4.228  …  214.5           │
│ 10    │ DAIMLER               │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 6735    │ missing  …  83.368        │
│ 11    │ DEUTSCHE BANK         │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 9.67  …  29.337           │
│ 12    │ DEUTSCHE BOERSE       │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 7329    │ missing  …  83.05         │
│ 13    │ DEUTSCHE POST         │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 7274    │ missing  …  28.344        │
│ 14    │ DEUTSCHE TELEKOM      │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 6229    │ missing  …  16.545        │
│ 15    │ E ON                  │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 2.194  …  12.369          │
│ 16    │ FRESENIUS MED.CARE    │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 6197    │ missing  …  77.352        │
│ 17    │ FRESENIUS             │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 5114    │ missing  …  61.234        │
│ 18    │ HEIDELBERGCEMENT      │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 9.113  …  73.201          │
│ 19    │ HENKEL                │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 6131    │ missing  …  89.24         │
│ 20    │ INFINEON TECHNOLOGIES │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 7094    │ missing  …  11.27         │
│ 21    │ K + S                 │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 0.757  …  37.848          │
│ 22    │ LANXESS               │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 8370    │ missing  …  54.341        │
│ 23    │ LINDE                 │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 6.239  …  178.101         │
│ 24    │ DEUTSCHE LUFTHANSA    │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 2.675  …  12.299          │
│ 25    │ MERCK KGAA            │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 5949    │ missing  …  94.85         │
│ 26    │ MUENCHENER RUCK.      │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 2.896  …  171.1           │
│ 27    │ RWE                   │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 5.95  …  19.969           │
│ 28    │ SAP                   │ Union{Float64, Missings.Missing} │ 4133    │ missing  …  65.98         │
│ 29    │ SIEMENS               │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 6.86  …  93.7             │
│ 30    │ THYSSENKRUPP          │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 3.449  …  23.941          │
│ 31    │ VOLKSWAGEN            │ Float64                          │ 0       │ 6.668  …  205.9           │
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. Does increasing 'rows_for_type_detect=11000' harm the performance? Would it be more efficient to specify the types of the columns?

Comment: yes - it harms the performance a bit; specifying types of columns will be faster (note that then you have to know which columns have missings); however, this data set reads in fast so this should not be a big difference.