# How do I replace "NA" with "missing" when using CSV.read in Julia?

Tags: csv, julia, na, missing-data

I have a csv file with a few NAs sprinkled in. Due to their presence, the columns containing the NAs are classified as strings rather than floats.

I just want to read the csv file with NAs in a way that Julia recognizes "NA" as a missing value rather than a string "NA." I tried the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875576/how-to-replace-na-with-missing-csv-read); however, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching CSV.File(::string; null="NA")
```

Any ideas on how to remedy this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `missingstring="NA"` keyword argument as described in the [documentation](https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/examples.html#missing_string_example).